# Popover segue option in storyboard segue style field is not showing

Tags: iphone, ios6, storyboard, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I want to choose storyboard segue style to be popover but dont see it in segue style field.

Story board Action segue presents only Push, modal and custom.

Have UIBarButtonItem for which i want to choose popover storyboard segue.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: just added a sample code for hard coding the popover view which you might be interested in.

Comment: was trying with uibutton. Thanks for help and your time. appreciate it.

Comment: changed it to uibutton but still dont see popover option. Actually it is uitableviewcontroller which i want as popover controller. That should not be a problem

Comment: Are you trying to do this in iPhone or iPad. In iPad you'll see it, but it is not available in iPhone. In iPhone you have to hard code a segue to pop over the current view and dismiss it.

Comment: no its ipad i m trying to do in. i dont see this even popover use explicit size even. howcome

Comment: In iPad you can not access the popover segue with any buttons, it is reserved for the viewcontroller in IB. You have to hard code the button and link the segue to it. Something similar to the sample code I provided you with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to simulated metrics and you should find it. Here is an image of where it is. Note that popover is available only in iPad not in iphone through simulator.

[image]

Edit:

Here is sample code for using a button and action method to create a popover:

You will need to declare a popoverController property:

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController* buttonPopoverController;
```

Then your button action can look something like this:

```
  - (void) buttonTapped:(UIButton*) sender
  {
  ContentViewController* contentVC = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
  self.buttonPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                 initWithContentViewController:contentVC];
  self.buttonPopoverController.delegate = self;  
       //only required if using delegate methods

 [self.buttonPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame
                       inView:self.view
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                     animated:YES];
  }
```

The ContentViewController is whichever view controller you are intending to segue to. If it is configured using a storyboard scene, you may want to do something like this when you create it:

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
  ContentViewController* contentVC = 
 [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController"];
```

You can set the storyboard identifier using the Identity Inspector when you have the relevant view controller selected in the storyboard.

Comment: So i have to replace UIBarbuttonItem with UIButton to select popover segue option

Comment: Well in iPad you can code in uibutton yes. And then use the segue to point to a anchor view which will be your popover view. I will update my answer with a sample code if you want.